# Is there any privacy issue in doing this hard-to-summarize thing with Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, security, privacy, bisq

I have a "hot" `wallet.dat` with no password, with a small amount of satoshis.

Recently, I transferred them all over to my Bisq wallet temporarily to make trades. So the hot wallet.dat has 0 BTC in it currently.

If I create a new receive address in the hot wallet.dat and send the Bisq balance to it, is this identical privacy-wise as it would be for me to create a new wallet.dat and send the balance to it instead?

To everyone else in the world, will this look identical, or is there some sort of "extra tell" which reveals that I just sent the money back to my own wallet rather than "somebody else's"?

Comment: Both approaches are safe enough and both are menaced by address reuse.

Comment: @Mercedes Safe enough? But are they the same? And what do you mean by the last part?

Comment: You can read about the dangers in address reuse, and then judge whether multiple wallets are worth to your Bitcoin use or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **If I create a new receive address in the hot wallet.dat and send the Bisq balance to it, is this identical privacy-wise as it would be for me to create a new wallet.dat and send the balance to it instead?**

The privacy implications should be the same. By themselves, addresses don't tell you anything. It is the way you *use* those addresses that has privacy implications and that applies equally in the two cases you describe.

> **is there some sort of "extra tell" which reveals that I just sent the money back to my own wallet**

Not in the way you mean.

Obviously if you, for example, later include some UTXO's from the new address with some UTXO's from an old address in a single transaction, observers may be able to make some inferences. There may be a higher probability of you unintentionally doing this if all the UTXOs are in one wallet.